# Join multiple tables where id may not exist

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables as follows:

```
table_a: id, title
table_b: id, table_a_id, status
```

I want to select the total number of entries in table_b for each value of table_a, as well as the total number of entries in table_b which do not reference table_a.

For example, let's say table_a has the values:

```
{id, title}
(1, "Value 1")
(2, "Value 2")
(3, "Value 3")
```

and table_b has the following entries

```
{id, table_a_id, status}
(1, 1, 'open')
(2, 1, 'closed')
(3, -, 'open')
(4, 2, 'closed')
```

What I am trying to get is something along the lines of:

```
("Value 1", 2)
("Value 2", 1)
("Value 3", 0)
(-, 1)
```

Without the nulls, I could write this as:

```
SELECT table_a.id, table_a.title, count(table_b.id) 
FROM table_a 
    LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.table_a_id
GROUP BY table_a.id, table_a.title
```

However, that doesn't give me the values for those entries in table_b which do not reference table_a. If I reverse the join, then I can get all values from table_b, but not from table_a. How can I get both in a single query?

Comment: You're using `GROUP BY` incorrectly. Please see [MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Comment: Is it ok to use `UNION`?

Comment: yes - union is ok. I'll fix the issue with the group by query - slapped this together pretty quickly.

Comment: @Elie could you select one answer as correct, please? If it's not the case, you're free to add your own answer, so the question does not reamins open

Comment: The solution I used is not presented here, but it also does not really answer the question. The answer you gave is close to a solution, but I was hoping for an answer that did not assemble multiple queries - though I'm aware I said that it was ok to do so. I'm going to leave this open for a little while longer before selecting a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using SQL Server, but I guess it'll work properly on MySQL too. The most important here is the `COALESCE` function, [and MySQL runs it the same way SQL Server does](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.title, '-'), COUNT(b.id)
FROM #table_b b
LEFT JOIN #table_a a ON b.table_a_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.title
UNION
SELECT a.title, 0
FROM #table_a a
LEFT JOIN #table_b b  ON b.table_a_id = a.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
SELECT 
  table_a.id, 
  count(table_b.id) 
FROM table_a 
    LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.table_a_id
GROUP BY table_a.id 

UNION

SELECT 
  table_a_id, 
  count(table_b.id) 
FROM table_b 
WHERE table_a_id not in (
  SELECT id from table_a
)    
GROUP BY table_a_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7d1b/6